# Pass the value in text box of View1 in View2 of asp.net mvc c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a text box in my View1, and I want to use it in View2. The 2 views is in the same Controller name but different Action. So what can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

titi you are working with MVC so the best approach is to have two text box say textbox1 for view1 and textbox2 for view2. Rendering view1 from Action1 and in Action2 get textbox1 value by

```
  public ActionResult Action2() 
    {
        string value= Request.Form["textBox1ID"];
        ViewBag.displayOnView2 = value;//if you are Using MVC2 use ViewData instead of viewbag
        return View();
    }
```

**View2** Display it like

```
@Html.TextBox("textBox2", (string)ViewBag.displayOnView2 )
```

**Updated**
First TextBox at **View1**

```
    <%using(Html.BeginForm())
         {
             Html.TextBox("textBox1ID");
          } %>
```

**Action2**

```
{
 string data= Request.Form["textBox1ID"] ;
 ViewData["data"]=data;
}
```

second TextBox at **View2**

```
Html.TextBox("textBox1ID",ViewData["data"]);
```

Comment: Better if you use ViewModels to store data

Comment: I tried this : `string user_name1 = Request.Form["u1"];
            ViewData["u1"] = u1;` in action of my View2, But when I display it, it is empty. Can u explain how to rendering view1 from action 1 to me please?

Comment: titi check if you are getting some value/data at user_name or not(by breakpoint)?

Comment: @titi i updated my ans have a look(request.form works with form elements only you can also use Request.QueryString/QueryString retrieves the values of the variables in the HTTP query string)

Answer (score 2):

Put the textbox in a partial view and use that
http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/

partial views allow you to isolate out common pieces of the viewing portion of the application and therefore reuse them when you need to.